# Reading password protected CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I want PHP program to read csv file. I am done with simple CSV file reading by getting URL and passing appropriate variables into that URL. But in my project to open CSV file login is required. How Can I do it with PHP program. I want to logged in by program and read that csv file. Later on I will implement it in zend code.

here is some code:

```
$url = "";
$handle = fopen($url, "r");
$row = fgetcsv($handle);
$_SESSION['variable_from_csv'] = $row[1];
fclose($handle);
```

In my case this is the URL .. 
http://retsmd.com/index.php?action=export&r_resource=Property&r_class=ResidentialProperty

but it's asking for password.

Comment: So your problem is nothing at all to do with CSV files, and everything to do with downloading a file tou your server from a password protected site - suggest you read up on curl

Comment: CSV files do not have passwords, the resource you are getting it from does. Which is presumably the web server/service in that there Url

Comment: Yes.. @TonyHopkinson.. But, What is the way to get into that server and grab this file by means of PHP?

Comment: for that you'd need to send credentials with the GET request, which isn't advised.

Comment: It depends on how you can log in to the site. If you can set an HTTP Basic Auth header, that's not very complex. If you need to login elsewhere and store some cookies, that's more complex. We don't know. Investigate.

Comment: You'd have to ask them, it's their file. Presumably you set up a user with them and log in. I'd be surprised if simply attaching credentials in the get request works.